# Assign a random password to all existing users

Tags: shell-script, users, password

I want to grep the users (first column) from the /etc/passwd file and assign them a password. I only want to do this for user accounts and not default system accounts. So far I have a simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /usertempfile
grep "/home" /etc/passwd |grep -v "/bin/false"|grep -v "/sbin/nologin"|grep -v $USER |awk -F":" '{print $1}' >> /userstempfile
for i in $(cat /usertempfile); do
    echo -e "password/npassword" |passwd $i
done
rm -rf /usertempfile
```

The script is able to extract the users from the /etc/passwd file that are not a default system account but is unable to change the passwords of the users which are in that file. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Hm, is that really `echo -e "password/npassword"` in your script and not `\n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `chpasswd` in my script and it's working fine for me:

```
echo "$USERNAME:$NEWPASSWORD" | chpasswd
```

PS: for not root user use `sudo` before `chpasswd`

```
echo "$USERNAME:$NEWPASSWORD" | sudo chpasswd
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at this too: [Setting a randomly generated password to a variable?](https://askubuntu.com/a/499651/560233)